# Eigenfunctions.

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

I have the following ODE:
$$y''-2xy'+2\alpha y=0$$
whose solution $y(x)$ may be recursively represented as:
$$a_{n+2} = \frac{a_n(2n-2\alpha)}{(n+2)(n+1)}$$
I have found the eigenvalues to be $-2\alpha$, however I find the manner whereby the eigenfunctions are found to be rather perplexing. I'd sincerely appreciate an explanation. For instance, I know that for $\alpha=0$, $a_2=\frac{a_0(0 - 0)}{2}$, but why would that entail $y_0(x) = a_0$? I mean, how was that derived?

Comment: Do you want solution of the given differential equation?

Comment: Not really, I am mainly interested in understanding how the first three eigenfunctions may be determined in the above case. Could you help?

Comment: I do not know how to find them out if the boundary values are absent. Other members will come with solution.

Comment: I am surprised no one has yet replied. Could there be something amiss with the fomulation of my question?

Answer (score 0):

I think its a type of Airy differential equation, which is itself a Bessel equation of order $1/3$.

There are 2 distinct solutions, the symmetric set are infinite at zero, like   $cosec(x)$ - this is not a solution, just the graphs are similar.

The second set are antisymmetric like   $sin(x)$ - again not a solution, just similar graph.

The system under consideration probably -> 0 for large $x$ and finite within region of interest;

Since antisymmetric $y(0)=0$.